# Поиск слова из заданного словаря по нескольким известным буквам

Tags: алгоритм, поиск, словари

Дан словарь слов разной длины (примерно 1500 слов). На входе дается несколько букв (от 3 и больше). Порядок следования букв в слове может быть неизвестен или может быть известно, что данная буква идет впереди остальных (порядок остальных неизвестен).

Подскажите алгоритм поиска всех подходящих слов из словаря?

Comment: Очевидно полным перебором словаря и сравнением букв (раз словарь не отсортирован)

Comment: @Mike да? Извините не был ознакомлен. Спасибо что пояснили

Comment: @SeeSharp Ну оно так должно быть. [Алгоритм] для этого. А что хочет ТС в данном конкретном случае понять сложно :)

Comment: Сдаётся, что для быстрого поиска стоит словарь дополнить специальным полем.

Comment: каким? Как их сгруппировать? Просто получается нужно перебирать со всеми возможными комбинациями букв

Answer (score 0):

Можете дополнить каждое слово в словаре битовым полем, в котором будут проставлены биты входящих в слово букв. Например, для русского языка и слова "Абя" значение будет `11000..0001`. Далее при поиске, делайте такое битовое поле введенных букв (например, ввели ая, будет `1000..0001`) и сравнивайте с полем в словаре по `И`. Если значение будет равно полю - значит все буквы в слове есть.

Правило поиска для "данная буква идет впереди остальных" не совсем понятно, уточните.

Comment: "данная буква идет впереди остальных" - иногда будет известен порядок букв (одной или всех), т.е. например в искомом слове буква "а" будет идти перед буквами "в" и "е".